# Given 800 people, 200 watch TV show A only, 250 watch B only, and 50 watch both, what is the probability of selecting someone who watches A or B?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Here's a better version of the question: What is the probability of randomly selecting a person who watches either telejournal A or telejournal B from a group of 800 people surveyed, where 200 people only watch A, 250 people only watch B, and 50 people watch both A and B?

My reasoning was:

By the principle of inclusion and exclusion:

|A or B| = |A| + |B| - |A and B|

|A or B| = 200 + 250 - 50 = 400

Now we have P(A or B) = 400/800 = 0.5

But I got a wrong answer and the following solution:

P(A) = (200 + 50)/800 = 250/800

P(B) = (250 + 50)/800 = 300/800

P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)

P(A or B) = 250/800 + 300/800 - 50/800 = 500/800 = 0.625

Why do you have to add the intersection to find, for example, P(A), since it also includes people who watch B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applying the inclusion-exclusion principle, "A" is the set of people who watch A *at all*, and "B" is the set of people who watch B *at all*, but you've inserted the numbers of people who watch "only A" and "only B". People who "watch both" are members of *both* sets A and B.